# Register Computer in Landscape "not enough licenses available"

Tags: landscape

I have 10 "Remaining virtual machine registrations" but I am not able to register any Computer. Neither a "normal" Ubuntu installation (bare metal) nor a LXC-Container or a VirtualBox machine.

The command I used:

```
landscape-config --computer-title "My Web Server" --account-name <account name>
```

worked without an error.

But in Landscape, when I try to accept the computer, I receive an error

> not enough licenses available

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Peter did you actually buy licenses from Canonical? Or are you within the 30-day trial period?

Comment: @guntbert - We have bought 10 licenses for virtual machines that is what puzzels me. The Landscape dashboard shows 10 availabe lisences. But I am not able to register any system. Even in the 30-day trail period I should be able to add computers to Landscape. Thanks Peter

Answer (score 2):

If you have Landscape licenses you should be entitled to support as an Ubuntu Advantage customer.  Please raise the issue via that route.

For the record, we don't currently recognise either LXC or VirtualBox as virtualisation hosts - that's a technical statement, not a statement of intent (i.e. I don't know if we actually intend that behaviour).  As it stands the Landscape client recognises Xen, OpenVZ, VMWare, HyperV and KVM (including OpenStack) as virtual machine types.

Comment: Thanks for the answser. I suspected such a thing. We will contact the support and try to find a solution.